# Compare int and string in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3 with spring boot 2

have a integer and a string to do a compare

i tried

```
${car.id}==${generic.value}"
```

but it's always false

Comment: try "'${car.id}'==${generic.value}"

Comment: that don't work

Comment: "${#strings.toString(car.id)}==${generic.value}"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should help you: `${#strings.equals(generic.value, #strings.toString(car.id))}`

Comment: How can we compare two Long values?