# Spring boot thymeleaf for each statement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

on the docotrs home page after signing in, i'm trying to write a for each statement in Spring boot thymeleaf that will pull and only display patients that have the my_doc_id that matches the doctorId.
so something along the lines of

```
th:if{user.doc_id = user.my_doc_id} {
<h3 th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}"></h3>
}
```

but i know that's not right at all and i have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

There are various ways to accomplish this general problem.  Here is one.

You can use `th:each` to iterate through your list. If the IDs are equal, print the statement.  You can optionally remove the `<span>` tag with `th:remove="tag"`.

```
<th:block th:each="user : ${doctorList}">
    <th:block th:if="${user.doc_id == my_doc_id}">
        <span th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}" th:remove="tag">[First Name, Last Name]</span>
    </th:block>
</th:block>
```

The test for equality will vary depending on the types that you are comparing.  For example, if you are comparing an int and string, you can use `${#strings.equals(generic.value, #strings.toString(user.doc_id))}` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142442/compare-int-and-string-in-thymeleaf).

`th:block` is nice because it doesn't create HTML tags at all, so you can use that as needed.  It becomes a little tougher to read with many nested blocks though.